# Reference UIButton by title?

Tags: ios, uibutton

In my view, I have 10 UIButtons each have a tag and a title. I can access one of the buttons by using

```
int i;
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[view viewWithTag:i];
```

Is there a similar way to access the button via its title? something like [view buttonWithTitle:title]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to iterate through each button and compare its title against the title you are looking for. But this is not a good approach. Titles can change or you may support your app in multiple languages. Using a tag is the better approach. Give each button its own tag and it is easy to lookup each one. Then get the title of the button if you need it.

Comment: If all my buttons are referenced in an outlet collection, how would I access a single button with a specific title? i.e. When I am using a searchfield, how can I identify a button in the ouletcollection that has a title equal to the searchfield text?

Comment: As I stated, you need to iterate each button. There is no built in method for getting a button with a specific title. If each button is assigned to a different variable then you need to check each variable. For each one, get the button's title and compare it against your search field.

Comment: Thanks, I decided this was the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could conceivably make a dictionary of the buttons keyed by their titles, by iterating through the buttons sort of like this:

```
NSArray *buttons = (your buttons);
NSMutableDictionary *buttonDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (UIButton *button in buttons) {
  [buttonDict setObject:button forKey:[button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]];
}
```

But rmaddy is right, it's really not a good idea to reference your buttons by their titles like that.  If you want to have them individually identified, you could make `UIButton` instance variables that are descriptively named and just assign your buttons to the ivars in `viewDidLoad`, so you always know where to find them.